# Meteor multiple files for schema and collections

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using Meteor, is it possible to separate collections and schemas into multiple files each? Say each separate schema gets its own file and the same goes for collections. Is there a way to set it up so that inside of the lib directory there is a schemas directory with multiple files each containing a single schema or a subset of schemas.

Specifically what I want to do is to leave all of the collection information in one file, but split out the schemas so that each page of the site has a file dedicated to its schemas. I split out the schemas into different files and put an underscore in front, but only a few seemed to work and the rest broke the pages they were apart of.

```
├── Collections
│   ├── Collections.js
│   ├── _lists.js
│   ├── _in.js
│   ├── _issues.js
│   ├── _reports.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make sure the schema file comes before the collection file, because after you create the collection, you'll need to attach the schema. No need to use the lib folder, I think common practice is to set them in a `collections` folder. If the schema is alphabetically before the collection, you're all good (just make sure not to use `var` or put the schema on a global object).

That said, a collection file is 2 lines (create, attach) plus a couple methods. Might as well toss the schema on top of that. You'll still have a file under 100 lines (unless your schema is huge). For subschemas, you can have something like `_shared.js`. That's where I put schemas like `address` so multiple collections (`clients` and `vendors`) can share it.